# How to assign multiple IPv6 Alias addresses to one network interface

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv6

I have an IPv6 Range which i am trying to assign on a centos6 server. I have updated my below files for IPv6 configuration:

```
[root@test ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
HOSTNAME=test.techsuccor.com

[root@test ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=82:d7:5d:50:c9:86
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=8ea314f3-d89a-4a5c-9ede-64b6675cae71
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=180.149.X.X
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

DNS2=206.183.X.X
GATEWAY=180.X.X.X
DNS1=206.X.X.X
IPV6INIT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6ADDR=2001:0df3:3cXX::X/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2001:0df3:3cXX::1
[root@test ~]#
```

With the above configuration am able to ping the single main ipv6 ipaddress in & out.

Using the IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES option am also able to add Alias IP's and ping them in and out

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2001:0df3:3cXX::X1/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X2/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X3/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X4/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X5/64"
```

What I actually need to do is assign full ipv6 range to the single NIC as alias ip's in one go. I can do this with below command

```
[root@test ~]# for ip in {4..10}; do /sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 inet6 add 2001:0df3:3c00::${ip}/64; done
```

Also after I run this command, I see my ipv6 ip's with ifconfig command as below but only the main IPv6  ping's and none of the Alias Ip ping from outside. Also is restart newtork all ip's go away.

```
[root@test ~]# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:D7:5D:50:C9:86  
          inet addr:180.149.XX.XX  Bcast:180.149.XX.XX Mask:255.255.255.0
          **inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::10/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::3/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::4/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::5/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::80d7:5dff:fe50:c986/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::6/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::8/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:df3:3c00::9/64 Scope:Global**
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:312539319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1808219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22772397919 (21.2 GiB)  TX bytes:312003644 (297.5 MiB)
          Interrupt:165 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2295915 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:2295915 (2.1 MiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it looks like the `IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES` should support a range format in initscripts-ipv6:

> 3ffe:ffff::1f-2a
>
> ```
> will set a range from "3ffe:ffff::1f" to "3ffe:ffff::2a"
> ```

([docs](https://www.deepspace6.net/projects/initscripts-ipv6.html#idm139977621729072))

In practice, Redhat's NetworkManager doesn't appear to support that format.

Answer (score -1):

I think can achieve this target by adding multiple secondary IPv6 addresses, please edit your file as you did before, `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file and you add in this format (remove ***);

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2001:0df3:3cXX::X1/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X2/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X3/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X4/64 \
2001:0df3:3cXX::X5/64"
```

If the issue still persist, please create Virtual Adapters for this and hope this will solve you issue.

Comment: I am aware of this solution which i have already posted. IPv6 range has so many ip's in it. What in case if i have to add 800-900 ip's should i keep adding it manually ? i need a solution where i can add it in one go giving a start and end point IP.